# Python while not True or False

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to use a while loop to keep asking for an input value if the value supplied is not 'yes' or 'no'?  e.g

```
someVar = None

while someVar is not (True or False):

  someVar = str.lower(input())

  if someVar == 'yes':
      someVar = True

  elif someVar== 'no':
      someVar = False
```

Comment: `True or False` is `True` (that's how `or` works).  You need to compare it against each value.

Comment: Ah of course, I don't know how I didn't notice that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

Once the condition has been met, use `break`:

```
while True:
    someVar = str.lower(input())

    if someVar == 'yes':
        someVar = True
        break
    if someVar == 'no':
        someVar = False
        break
```

You can also use `while False` with:

```
met = True

while met:

   someVar = str.lower(input())

   if someVar == 'yes':
        someVar = True
        break
    if someVar == 'no':
        someVar = False
        break
```

Since all strings are `True`, use another variable to store either `True` or `False`. Once `met` is `false`, then the loop will break.

Comment: But I need to have someVar set to either true or false, so would I just add break after the `someVar = True` line ?

Comment: @AshleyB You don't really need that since you have `break` and your input would be gone

Comment: I need someVar to hold a the response value e.g if the question is 'Do you like Python?', then if they enter 'yes', someVar would be `True` etc. does that make sense?

Comment: @AshleyB Then use another variable to be `True` or `False`. Also, if `someVar` contains *any* string, it will **always** be `True`

Comment: @AshleyB So you deliberately want `someVar` to be `True` and `False` right?

Comment: Correct, I've accepted your answer as correct as it was 90% of the way there before the edit, and was due to me not adequately specifying the requirements. The edit is exactly what I wanted, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
someVar = None

while (True):

   someVar = str.lower(input())

   if someVar == 'yes':
      someVar = True
      break

   elif someVar == 'no':
      someVar = False
      break
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of my answer by using `break`

Comment: Not really. I've set someVar to True or False based on what the user enters. I think that's what OP wanted.

Comment: Well `someVar` was set like that by the OP in an attempt to make a condition to make the loop break. With `break`, it is now not needed

Comment: This is what I was asking for @AnthonyPham - I understand the confusion but this actually sets `someVar` to a True/False which is what I wanted. The mistake was by me using `someVar` in the loop guard, and not mentioning explicitly that someVar has to be set to True or False.